# Set IIS Website Application to use Application Pool identity for Anonymous authentication (via code)

Tags: .net, iis-7

[I can see here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/anonymousauthentication) how to enable anonymous authentication and specifically set a username and password for the credentials. Can anyone tell me if it's possible using .NET to set the credentials to use the Application Pool's identity instead?  I don't see a way of doing that programmatically.

[image]

```
    Public Sub CreateApplication(ByVal website As String, ByVal application As String, ByVal path As String, applicationPoolName As String)

        Using manager As New ServerManager()
            manager.Sites(website).Applications.Add("/" & application, path)
            manager.CommitChanges()
            manager.Sites(website).Applications("/" & application).ApplicationPoolName = applicationPoolName

            Dim config As Configuration = manager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration
            Dim anonymousAuthenticationSection As ConfigurationSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication", website & "/" & application)
            anonymousAuthenticationSection("enabled") = True
            manager.CommitChanges()
        End Using

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late reply (hopefully it will help someone) you can set it to use the application pool identity by simply setting the username and password blank for that part of the config e.g.

( excuse the C# syntax )

```
        var config = _IIS.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
        var anonymousAuthenticationSection = config.GetSection( "system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication", name );
        anonymousAuthenticationSection[ "enabled" ] = true;
        //use app pool user
        anonymousAuthenticationSection[ "userName" ] = "";
        anonymousAuthenticationSection[ "password" ] = "";
```

Comment: WOW - can't wait to try this out!